# divider не на всех итемах ListView

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть ли какой-то способ отобразить divider не на всех итемах ListView, а только на одном, допустим?

Спасибо.

Comment: Вот немного информации, может поможет: [Hiding ListView Header / Hiding Single Divider in a List](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4625832/2546083) и [remove bottom divider of a android listview](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5118444/2546083)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Готового механизма нет, но Вы можете скрыть стандартный разделитель, указав в `ListView` `android:divider="@android:color/transparent"`, в layout строк добавить `ImageView`, который будет имитировать разделитель, и в адаптере самостоятельно управлять его видимостью как того требует Ваш алгоритм.

Answer (score 1):

Для того, чтобы реализовать разный вид айтемов в одном списке (в вашем случае с дивидером и без него) в адаптере необходимо переопределить методы `getItemViewType()` и  `getViewTypeCount()`.

Для начала вам нужно убрать стандартные дивидеры списка:

```
<ListView
    android:divider="@null"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    ....
/>
```

Затем создать разметку для двух видов айтемов - с дивидером и без него, назовем их `layout_divider` и `layout_nodivider`

Следующим шагом создаем кастомный адаптер (для примера за основу взят ArrayAdapter, но наследоваться можно от любого другого) , для удобства определим константы, обозначающие тип нашего айтема:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

  int TYPE_DIVIDER = 0;
  int TYPE_NODIVIDER = 1;
```

В адаптере переопределяем метод `getViewTypeCount()`, который должен возвращать количество разных видов айтемов в списке, в нашем случае - 2 (с дивидером и без него)

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}
```

В адаптере переопределяем метод `getItemViewType(position)`, который должен возвращать, какой тип айтема отображать в текущей позиции:

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
  return (условие, когда выводить дивидер) ? TYPE_DIVIDER:TYPE_NODIVIDER;
}
```

В адаптере переопределяем метод `getView()`, который подготавливает нужный вид айтемов и назначаем айтему разметку в зависимости от его типа:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view;
    int type = getItemViewType(position);        
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = ((type == TYPE_DIVIDER) ? 
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_divider, parent, false): 
                    inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_nodivider, parent, false));
    }

  // прочая логика, определение ссылок на виджеты и тд.
  // если для разных типов айтемов используются разные виджеты и логика, то 
  // так же используется условие (type == TYPE_DIVIDER), чтобы их разделить.

return view;
}
```