# Android/Java. Как делается диалог чата с разделением на правую и левую стороны?

Tags: android, listview, view, adapter, chat

Как сделать диалог Чата такого вида?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот чтобы справа и слева отображалось при приеме и отправке соответственно..

Если бы там только текст был.. то можно было бы Gravity применять.. а там еще картинка.. это получается как то надо две заготовки и скрывать их????

или как то кастомные адаптеры создать? Если есть, приведите подобные кусочки кода..

У меня код такой:

```
public static class MySimpleAdapter extends SimpleAdapter {

   private List<HashMap<String, String>> results;
   private Context mContext;

   public MySimpleAdapter(Context context, List<HashMap<String, String>> data, int resource, String[] from, int[] to) 
    {
        super(context, data, resource, from, to);
        this.results = data;
        this.mContext = context;

    }

     public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
     {
        View v = view;
        if (v == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            v = vi.inflate(R.layout.mymsg, null);
        }


        if (!results.get(results.size()-1).containsKey("to")) 

        {           
        TextView tt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.mytxt);
        tt.setText(results.get(results.size()-1).get("msg"));
        v.findViewById(R.id.mymsg).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        v.findViewById(R.id.memsg).setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
        else
        {

        TextView tt= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.metxt);
        tt.setText(results.get(results.size()-1).get("msg"));

        v.findViewById(R.id.mymsg).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        v.findViewById(R.id.memsg).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }

        return v;
    }
}
```

И код отправки/приема:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(); 
try {
Message message = new Message();
message.setBody(msg.getText().toString()+ "\n");
sendMessage(message);
map.put("msg", message.getBody().toString());
map.put("to", message.getTo().toString());
usersList.add(map);
sadapter =  new MySimpleAdapter(getActivity(),  usersList, R.layout.mymsg, from, to);
listView.setAdapter(sadapter);
sadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
} catch (NotConnectedException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
```

Comment: создайте два layout'а для входящих и исходящих сообщений. А в getView просто проверяйте тип сообщения и создавайте нужный view.

Comment: вам нужен адаптер с двумя разными типами `View`

Comment: Нее.. у меня как то странно..я создал кастомный адаптер и когда вьюв задаю где проверка .. то в Listview у меня потом они все одинаковые становятся.. то есть я отправил левая сторона вьюва загрузилась - потом принял правая загрузилась и предыдущая тоже правая стала.. почему? может что то notifyDataSetChanged()?

Comment: Если у вас проблемы с кодом, не нужно "на словах" расказывать о них - приложите код.

Comment: Я добавил код. посмотрите.. люди, помогите..

Comment: аааа.. Возможно.. там надо смотреть position . if (position == results.size()-1){ и как то менять право лево наверное..

Comment: Смотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446242/177345), как выводить два типа айтемов в списке.

Answer (score 4):

План следующий:

1 - создать два типа леяута, для отображения исходящего и входящего сообщения
2 - в адаптере переопределить метод
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {}

3 - в `onBindViewHolder` инитить данные

Comment: Что за onBindViewHolder? Это метод?.., а гетВью который для чего? Посмотрите мой код.. который я добавил..

Comment: Это метод адаптера для RecyclerView, который предпочтительнее использовать. Т.к. с его использованием уже вшито применение паттерна вьюхолдер, с его помощью проще делать анимации элементов, он лучше ListView и гугл рекомендует использовать именно его. Поэтому лучше сразу учиться с ним работать и применять его.