# Несколько ListView в одном Activity

Tags: java, android, android-sdk

Стоит задача сделать вывод нескольких `ListView` на одном экране. Типа разные категории и под каждой категорией список элементов категории. Но что-то задача оказалась сложнее чем я думал. Я сделал это все фрагментами. В коде динамично добавлялись фрагменты с `layout`(который содержит `ListView` список элементов и `TextView` заголовок категории) в контейнер. Было на экране много фрагметов с `ListView`. Как озазывается `ListView` нельзя засунуть в `ScrollView`, потому что `ListView` начинает чудить и выводит только 1 элемент из всего списка. Я решил пойти другим путем и сделал вместо фрагметов `ListView` со своим адаптером. То есть я вместо динамичного добавления фрагментов сделал `ListView` который вставляет тот же `layout`, только не в качестве фрагмента, а в качестве фрагмента списка. Что бы это реализовать я переопределил `SimpleAdapter` и дописал там инициализию вложенных `ListView`. Но та же проблема. Только один элемент списка выводится. К тому же элементы списка теперь не нажимаются и вообще никак не реагируют на нажатия. Что делать? Как сделать нужную мне реализацию?

Comment: а решение с одним listview и 2 типа ячейки (1 для категории, 2 для элементов) не подходит?

Comment: @Yury Pashkov Типа вместо ListView сделать руками список?

Comment: нет, у вас будет один listView, просто он будет отображать два типа ячеек, одна будет отвечать за категорию, вторая за элемент категории, и в итоге получится в списке идет 1-ая категория, за ней ее элементы и так далее 2-ая и ее элементы... и все это без фрагментов. просто в layout у активити будет лежать listview

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446242/177345) по реализации списков с двумя типами айтемов