# Android SimpleAdapter изменение ресурса

Tags: java, android

Есть `ListView` в котором отображается история сообщений.

Так же есть `SimpleAdapter`

```
adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getContext(), messageList, R.layout.left_item,
                    new String[] { "text", "time" }, new int[]  {R.id.messageText, R.id.timeText });
messageListView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Сейчас в ListView добавляется соответственно `R.layout.left_item`

**Вопрос:**

Как можно добавить `R.layout_right_item` вместо `R.layout_left_item`

Сейчас добавляю сообщения так.

```
public void addMessageLeft(String text, String time) {
        HashMap<String, String> message = new HashMap<>();
        message.put("text", text);
        message.put("time", time);
        messageList.add(message);
}
```

Где `messageList` является `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>`.

Пробовал задать новый адаптер, но тогда все предыдущие левые сообщения заменяются на правые.

Ещё пробовал использовать `adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.right_item);` но я так понял это тут не поможет.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/446242/177345

Comment: @pavlofff В какой момент вызывается `getView()` ? При добавлении новых элементов?

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой проблемы, пришлось полностью скопировать код класса SimpleApapter в новый класс, т.к `private View createViewFromResource()` нельзя переопределить.
Изменения которые я внёс:

**Добавил поле**

`private ArrayList<Integer> mArrayList;`

**Дополнил конструктор:**

```
public MessageAdapter(Context context, List<? extends Map<String, ?>> data,
                     @LayoutRes int resource, String[] from, @IdRes int[] to, ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        mData = data;
        mResource = mDropDownResource = resource;
        mFrom = from;
        mTo = to;
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        mArrayList = arrayList;
}
```

**Изменил метод** `getView()` :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        return createViewFromResource(mInflater, position, convertView, parent,
                mArrayList.get(position) == 0 ? R.layout.left_item : R.layout.right_item);
}
```